# jQuery .load() html page with javascript inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, httpresponse

i have a problem with loading .html pages (with JavaScript inside) into a div element.

This is my div:

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

This is my php:

```
<?php
  if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");
  $page = (int)$_POST['page'];
  if(file_exists('pages/page_'.$page.'.html'))
    echo file_get_contents('pages/page_'.$page.'.html');
  else echo 'There is no such page!';
?>
```

This is my script:

```
var default_content="";
$(document).ready(function(){   
checkURL();
$('ul li a').click(function (e){
        checkURL(this.hash);
}); 
//filling in the default content
default_content = $('.content').html();     
setInterval("checkURL()",250);  
});
var lasturl="";
function checkURL(hash)
{
if(!hash) hash=window.location.hash;    
if(hash != lasturl)
{
    lasturl=hash;       
    // FIX - if we've used the history buttons to return to the homepage,
    // fill the pageContent with the default_content        
    if(hash=="")
    $('.content').html(default_content);        
    else
    loadPage(hash);
}
}

function loadPage(url)
{
url=url.replace('#page','');    
$('.content').css('visibility','visible');  
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "load_page.php",
    data: 'page='+url,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(msg){         
        if(parseInt(msg)!=0)            
        {
            $('.content').html(msg);        
        }
    }       
});
 }
```

When the page is loaded the JavaScript code inside the .html page isn't executed.
If i click on the browser reload button the JavaScript code is executed.

How can i execute the JavaScript inside the pages using jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your script does not make sense

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "load_page.php",
    data: 'page='+url,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(d){
        $('.content').html(d);        
    }       
});
```

is better and will execute javascrit page loaded from ajax

Comment: What's the difference except a variable being renamed?

Comment: @pimvdb: .load to .html and also explained that ajax-loaded content is executed automatically (that javascript is executed automatically)

Answer (score 1):

Are the jQuery event handlers binded with `live()` ?

http://api.jquery.com/live/

If javascript/jquery is attached to the dom after the page has loaded, normal `click()`, `change()` events wont be attached/executed.

You need to attach these events using `live()`.

```
$('#some_element').live('click', function(){});
```

`live()` will initialize the event handler whenever an element is attached to the page.